# Polymer, core-ajax shared response

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer, web-component

Using Polymer, I am attempting to instantiate several ajax-service elements using template binding, `<template repeat=...>`.

Code is as follows:

```
<template repeat="{{viewName, i in views}}">                           
      <section hash={{viewName}} layout vertical center-center on-tap={{closeOpenDrawer}}>
          <core-ajax id="ajaxService" auto response={{list}}" url="../componentsItems/demo-components.json"></core-ajax>
             <template repeat="{{element, j in list}}">
                 <workspace-elem class="dropped" name="{{element.name}}"></workspace-elem>
             </template>     
       </section>
</template>
```

The problem is, each ajax response is concatenated to a shared list variable, rather then instantiating its own local list variable per repeated template, so when the sub template is triggered, it generates `<workspace-elem>`s in each section for the sum of data from all ajax calls.

Is there an easy way to solve this?  Is there something I am over looking?

EDIT:

Same sort of problem occurs with the inner template.  Each instantiated inner template shares the list variable, if anything is pushed to template.model.list, all instantiated template models are updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `response={{list}}` in the template, you are not creating that variable, but you are binding the value of the response attribute to an existing variable called ‘list’.

The question you need to ask yourself is: ‘Where does the “list” variable that I'm binding to come from?’ It is not obvious from the snippet you mention, but it's very likely that it's coming from some enclosing custom element, so it's only natural that it will be shared between the iterations of the template (though I'm surprised that it get concatenated instead of overwritten…). I think a good solution would be to encapsulate the code you have in the outer template in a custom element to hold the variable:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" attributes="viewName">
   <template>
     <!--Your original code starts here-->
     <section hash={{viewName}} layout vertical center-center>
      <core-ajax id="ajaxService" auto response={{list}}" url="../componentsItems/demo-components.json"></core-ajax>
         <template repeat="{{element, j in list}}">
             <workspace-elem class="dropped" name="{{element.name}}"></workspace-elem>
         </template>     
   </section>
   <!--Your original code ends here-->
   </template>
   <script>
     Polymer({
       publish: {
         list: null
       },
       created: function() {
          // Create your array on instantiation of an element
          this.list = [];
       }
     }
   </script>
</polymer-element>

<template repeat="{{viewName, i in views}}">                           
    <my-element on-tap={{closeOpenDrawer}}></my-element>
</template>
```

I think that should solve your problem. Alternatively, I think it might help to make the outer template an auto-binding template(‘`is="auto-binding"`’). Then the model of the template would be the template itself, but since I have not used this facility very often, I'm not quite sure (it might be that you're then loosing the ability to bind to ‘views’).

Comment: Ah I see, that way the list variable is private to each instantiated element.  Sounds good thanks!